# Video preview image using vlc-qt (or libvlc directly)

Tags: c++, image, qt, libvlc, vlc-qt

I'd like to make a detailed video list in my Qt application using vlc-qt. Other playback engines such as QtAV or QtMultimedia are not an option. It should be vlc-qt (libvlc). That's why I need to get a small picture of a video, a preview, but can't find anything suitable for this task, except [`libvlc_video_take_snapshot`](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__video.html#ga9b0a3870ce962aa0358050b2d5a59143). This method will save a picture locally, and I guess it needs a real render window to exist. That's not a good variant for me, maybe there's some better solution?

Comment: I think it's possible with [libvlc_video_set_format_callbacks + libvlc_video_set_callbacks](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__media__player.html#ga612605f2e5c638d9f4ed59021d714bf0). If you need some example, I have c++ wrapper for it on github

Comment: @RSATom, thanks for your reply, can you please give me a link to an example?

Comment: [vlc_vmem.h](https://github.com/RSATom/ya-libvlc-wrapper/blob/master/vlc_vmem.h), [vlc_vmem.cpp](https://github.com/RSATom/ya-libvlc-wrapper/blob/master/vlc_vmem.cpp)